# UITextField disable cursor

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextinput

Is there way to disable blinking cursor in UITextField? Probably messing with UITextInput protocol? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Didn't found solution. I made own class implementing UIKeyInput.

Answer (score 0):

This is old and you found a new solution. But there are an idea you can use. I thing the cursor is a image animation, so you can found their view.

Run thought all views with

```
for (id subview in myTextField.subviews) {
    if (is cursor view){
        subview.hidden = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Maybe this can work, but it is trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to do it would be to set the **tint color** to **clear** as follows:

`textField.tintColor = .clear`